# translate3d on html doesn't affect background-position on body in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, translate3d

When I do:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 35px, 0px) !important;
transform: translate3d(0, 35px, 0px) !important;
```

on the HTML tag.

Chrome pushes everything down (including the body background with a position), but Firefox doesn't do so.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6VTAn/ (Open in Chrome and Firefox to notice the difference)

Is there an additional style/property that I can apply to the HTML tag that makes it exhibit the same behavior as Chrome.

I'm looking for a standard approach to push the page down across all websites and browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which version of firefox you are using, you may need the moz prefix: `-moz-transform: translate3d(0,35px,0)`

Comment: Agreed, but this doesn't seem to produce the desired behavior either.

Comment: What version of firefox are you using? Seems to be working fine in 24.0

Comment: I'm using 28.0. When I said desired behavior, I meant that I expected to see a behavior similar to Chrome where the Background gets pushed down due to the 3d transform.